# Issue with the azure cloud service project when i update from Azure sdk 2.1 to azure sdk 2.9

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Team,

I am a beginner in Azure stuff and need your advice. I have recently updated my Azure cloud service application from SDK 2.1 to SDK 2.9.  But now the Azure cloud service role errors saying that "Invalid service definition or service configuration".

The XML specification is not valid: The 'schemaVersion' attribute is invalid - The value '2013-03.2.0' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition:SchemaVersion' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

and many such errors like

Error       Role: 'ABCApplication', setting 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.NamedCaches' in all service configurations could not be found in the service definition.

How should I fix the above?

My question is Do i have to publish to the azure portal to get a new service definition or service config. Did the azure SDK update affect anything here?

Or do i have to make changes in the service definition or config according to the new SDK?

Please help.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes , in fact i tried the same thing but did not help. So i created a new azure cloud project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best would be to create a new cloud project with the existing web application a web role to it. Ofcourse there would be a pain to recreate the device definition and service config from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

In consideration of your used SDK has changed, per my experience, the first one you need to do is to update the `schemaVersion` in your XML file for the verification.

The schemaVersion for the Azure SDK 2.9 is `schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6"` that can be got and verified by creating a new Azure Cloud project targeting Azure SDK 2.9 and looking at the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file. Then you can re-compile and re-publish it to upgrade your service to check whether it works.

Comment: Hello Jay,  thanks for your reply. But the same i had tried befre but did not help. So, i created a new Azure clud project with new service config and service def and then proceeded. Am still not sure what got the older project corrupted.